# How do cmd arguments are loaded to process memory before they're passed to main?

Tags: command-line

My question is how cmd arguments are passed from the shell to the process memory ?
How the loader loads them and if there are passed with some sort of syscall ?
ill be happy if some one can explain in details or point to a relevant article.

Comment: Which OS are you speaking about ?

Comment: Linux mainly, but windows will be helpful to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows, the Loader will copy the parameters into the process' address space during process setup. Specifically it happens when the Address Space is initialized

See Stage 3D Step 8 in [Windows Internals](https://books.google.com/books?id=w65CAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT584&lpg=PT584&dq=windows%20internals%20%22The%20user%20process%20parameters%20are%20written%20into%20the%20process%22&source=bl&ots=4Wn5n4Sg0u&sig=F8TVaIpJaDa2buSPQUKsX0PzRyw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIrouQ4bnlyAIViCqICh3D3ACU#v=onepage&q=windows%20internals%20%22The%20user%20process%20parameters%20are%20written%20into%20the%20process%22&f=false):

> 8. The user process parameters are written into the process, copied, and fixed up (meaning converted from absolute form to a relative form
>      so that a single memory block is needed).

Answer (score 1):

You can read about system calls called `fork` and `execve` including kernel implementation.

User land implementations:

[fork and other usage examples](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html)

[man page of execve including example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

[Kernel implementation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/097f70b3c4d84ffccca15195bdfde3a37c0a7c0f/fs/exec.c)